# kind of non-visual frequency histogram in C

Tags: c, histogram, frequency

I would like to make a kind of frequency histogram. I have a binary file describing a song with double between -1 and 1 ( like -0.001235 ) and i would like to make a fonction that gives me the number of values between 0.9 and 1 for example. But where it's not easy for, it that the space of interval can change.

It's like, I want 40 or 50 or 100 interval between -1 and 1, and couting the number of double in those interval. Is it all clear ? ^^'

e.g : [-1,-0.9] -> 152 values .... [-0.9,-0.8] -> 34 values ....

I have already an array of 1024 frequency `double (*tab)[1024];` thank you for your help :)

Comment: If you have to ask "Is it all clear ?", then no, it is not.

Comment: Also, please show what you have tried. This is a coding help service, not a code writing service.

Comment: Why do you have a pointer to an array of 1024 doubles? Don't you mean `double *tab[1024]`?

Comment: see the last answer I've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a function which counts all frequences in an interval in on table:

```
int countinterval( double *tab, int tabsize, double min, double max )
{
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < tabsize; i ++ )
    {
        if ( tab[i] >= min && tab[i] < max ) // test if frequency is in interval [min,max[
        // if ( tab[i] >= min && tab[i] <= max ) // test if frequency is in interval [min,max]
            count ++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Next you need a function which sums the results of each table.

```
int counttabsinterval( double *tab[], int tabsize, int tabcount, double min, double max )
{
    int count = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < tabcount; i ++ )
        count += countinterval( tab[i], tabsize, min, max ); // sums results
    return count;
}
```

Call the function for each interval where you want to know number of frequencies.

```
double *tab[1024];
int tabsize = ???; // <- init with size of one table
int count1 = counttabsinterval( tab, tabsize, 1024, -1.0, -0.9 );
int count2 = counttabsinterval( tab, tabsize, 1024, -0.9, -0.8 );
```

Here is a function which calculates the Quantitative Frequency Distribution for on table `tab` with lenght of table `tabsize` ans stores the result in an array `dist`with length `distcount`.

```
void QuantitativeFrequencyDistribution( double *tab, int tabsize, double *dist, int distcount )
{
    int count = 0;
    double intervallAmount = 2.0 / distcount;
    for ( int i = 0; i < distcount; i ++ )
    {                            
        double min = -1.0 + i*intervallAmount;
        double max = min + intervallAmount;
        dist[i] = countinterval( tab, tabsize, min, max );
    }
}

int sizeOfTab = ?;// <- init with size of table
double *tab; // <- your table
int distcount = 20; // for example
double dist[distcount];
QuantitativeFrequencyDistribution( tab, sizeOfTab, dist, distcount );
```

If you have different tables with different lengths and you want to know the Quantitative Frequency Distribution over all tables, you have to call `QuantitativeFrequencyDistribution` for each single table and calculate sum of the results.

Comment: Yep i'm agree with your 2first function, but, it's on the third i have problem.. i don't understand what you want to do with tabsize, and the nomber of interval is a variable, so i can't modify my program each time the number of interval change. U understand ? Ty

Comment: look at this site, i want to do the PART A 
https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/dgurney/Math241/StatTopics/HistGen.htm

Comment: it was really helpfull, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I made those 2 function. that count the frequence of apparition of values between N interval between -1 and 1

```
int countInterval(double *tab, double min, double max){
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < POINTS; i++){
        if (tab[i] >= min && tab[i] < max) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int *countWindow(double *tab){
    // interval +1
    double interv = INTERVALLES;
    int *interval = (int*)malloc(sizeof(INTERVALLES)), i, debug = 0;
    double lb = 2/interv;
    double min = -1;
    double max = min + lb;

    if (debug==1) {
        printf("lb : %f\n",lb);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < INTERVALLES; i++){
        interval[i] = countInterval(tab, min, max);
        if (debug==1) {
            printf("min = %f - max = %f - count = %d\n", min, max, interval[i]);
        }
        min += lb;
        max = min + lb;
    }
    return interval;
}
```

I give a `double *tab` (10 for example) :

```
0.004517
0.030243
0.014862
0.005188
0.002289
0.026917
-0.013641
0.017395
0.032867
0.036072
```

and i have a result like that :

```
lb : 0.400000
min = -1.000000 - max = -0.600000 - count = 0
min = -0.600000 - max = -0.200000 - count = 0
min = -0.200000 - max = 0.200000 - count = 10
min = 0.200000 - max = 0.600000 - count = 0
min = 0.600000 - max = 1.000000 - count = 0
```